# Nice error message display for some database exceptions of Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I found the following code, which modified the default `error.cshtml`, to display some nice messages for some database errors; for example, it shows a nice "Cannot insert duplicated value (xxxx) in YYYYY" instead of a general error message to prevent user from keeping inserting the same value again and again frustratingly.

However, the code seems very ugly. Is there a better way to display the error message of Exceptions for end users?

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
@{
    const string FK = @"^The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint.*? table ""(?<name>[^""]*)"",";
    const string DuplicateKey = @"^Cannot insert duplicate key row.*?The duplicate key value is \((?<value>[^(]*)\)";
    var ex = Model.Exception.InnerException;
    if (ex != null && ex.InnerException != null) 
    {
        string message;
        if (Model.ActionName == "Delete")
        {
            var re = new Regex(FK);
            var match = re.Match(ex.InnerException.Message);
            if (match.Success) 
            { 
                message = string.Format(
                    "The {0} has been used in {1}. Cannot delete the {0} unless referenced record(s) is(are) deleted.", 
                    Model.ControllerName, match.Groups["name"].Value.Replace("dbo.", ""));
            }
            else
            {
                message = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
        if (Model.ActionName == "Create")
        {
            var re = new Regex(DuplicateKey);
            var match = re.Match(ex.InnerException.Message);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                message = string.Format("Cannot insert duplicated value ({1}) in {0}.", 
                    Model.ControllerName, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
            else
            {
                message = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            message = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }

        //.........

        <h3 class="text-danger">@message</h3>
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception messages are for developers; *not* end users.

Comment: @AntP Yes Exception messages are too technical. That's why the code extracts some information from the exception message and re-generates nice end-user readable messages.

Comment: No, you miss my point. The exception message is a *technical reason* for failure. All the user needs to know is that something isn't working right (and potentially an error code that they can report). You shouldn't be relaying *any* exception info to your users.

Comment: In addition to  @AntP "shouldn't be relaying any exception info" - unless you trust every user of the site to be nice an friendly *any* additional piece of technical information reported to the user opens a way to sneak into system. What if someone calls/mail support of your site with detailed steps to "fix" a problem (i.e. drop couple important tables) based on information glanced from error messages? Or simply finds out what exact method have SQL injection vulnerability and table names shown in error message?

Comment: @AntP, for example, it will raise exepction when user try to insert duplicated key records. Isn't it better to remind the user the record cannot be inserted (so user will know reason and skip the record) instead of showing a general error message?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 That shouldn't really be handled with an exception at all, but with a conditional as it isn't an *exceptional* case. Exceptions aren't for validation - you should prevent them from happening *at all* where possible.

Comment: +1 for "Exceptions aren't for validation". That might crash your app, your app pool and performance is thrown away with exceptions.

If you're looking into better user experience, submit data with ajax. Check if there's a duplicate BEFORE even trying to insert data and if yes (or if you really get an exception), return a json with an error message, to display as an alert into your page. You can even block your `submit` button until the user changes the key or whatever, to avoid re-submitting the same data.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to show user something like "Operation failed. Provide this 12345-5445-dfee44 value to site support for investigation" and dump exceptions to log file (or system even log, DB) along with the way to find it back.

Unless your application is for developers who are well aware of inner structure of your site every error message will be essentially "Operation failed" to the user anyway.